# facebook API how is onlogin called

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Can any one tell me how exactly the FB API works.
It looks to be a basic question but I am really confused.

Question:
I have onlogin(). When I click the login button, I am expecting it to call this function.
But in the code I pasted: I see that alert-test is printed first  and than the FB.api is called.

So, it looks like onlogin is called first, then the FB API ...is there a way I can call this function only once.

```
<body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({appId: 'XXX', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());

    function checkFacebookLogin() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        alert("Name: "+ response.name + "\nFirst name: "+ response.first_name + "ID: "+response.id);
    });

    alert('test');

    }

    </script>


 <p id="fb_login_button_1"><fb:login-button  onlogin="checkFacebookLogin();"  size="medium" scope="user_about_me">Sign in using Facebook</fb:login-button></p>


</body>v
```

My main issue is the function should be called only once....but it is getting called twice.

Comment: `click` and `onclick` do not appear in the code you have in your question, making it difficult to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({appId: 'XXX', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());

    function fetchUserDetail()
    {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                alert("Name: "+ response.name + "\nFirst name: "+ response.first_name + "ID: "+response.id);
            });
    }

    function checkFacebookLogin() 
    {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            fetchUserDetail();
          } 
          else 
          {
            initiateFBLogin();
          }
         });
    }

    function initiateFBLogin()
    {
        FB.login(function(response) {
           fetchUserDetail();
         });
    }
    </script>


 <input type="button" value="Sign in using Facebook" onclick="checkFacebookLogin();"/>


</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Purusottam, this solved my issue it is not printing 2 times. But I am not seeing FB colored button...In general people like to see that bluish window. because you are using "button: type I am missing that look and feel is that possible with "fb:login-button"

Comment: use CSS to have the same look and feel as FB button. If this solved your problem then mark it as an answer so that in future it may help others

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I cannot directly use FB apis". Every code which I used is FB APIs FB.login, FB.getLoginStatus and FB.api they all FB API calls.  FB.login and FB.getLoginStatus are specific function from FB JS SDK to initiate LOGIN and to check login status. Personally I am not big fan of SOCIAL PLUGINS given by FB itself (like login button) as they tend to restrict developer capabilitis.

Comment: I agree that you are helped me using the FB APIs. But I was looking at the look and feel to look like FB..the bluish button. because that is what people will be looking (in general for login)

Comment: I will posit as a separate q as you answered the question I was looking for

Comment: Pavan to give a same look and Feel as FB button you can use CSS. Ask any of your UI team member they can do it in 5 minutes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Request call to FB API is asynchronous. It means that once the request is sent, the code will not wait for the request to be completed. Because of this you get alert-test before the API Call is returned. All the FB API calls are asynchronous, if you try to make them synchronous then your browser will hang.

Thanks
Kaushik

Comment: Thank Kaushik. how can I make sure it is called only once ..I understand that as you said if I make it synchronous it hangs..how to get around? also why is alert-test called twice. As it is asyncronous it should call only once with out waiting for the FB response?  please also tell me how to make itcall only once

Comment: Hi Pavan... why you are using FB.api to check whether user is logged in OR not. Simply use FB.login function. Secondly why are you using fb:login-button? if you use this then you are probably messing up FB Social plugin. My suggestion will be simply create HTML button and then onclick call your function. For more details refer this link. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I am looking at 2 things the user to login and then I want to get the information of the user who logged in to my data base.so I am using FB.api. yes it is really messed up with the button. Can you please let me know what you mean and how to use that ...all I need is validation should be done by FB and I want to get that user information logged....As I said in the above example it is executing twice..infact the alert of the user information is also printed twice..I still did not understand the reasoning

Comment: Hi Pavan I have modified your code and put it as another answer. Please check if this solves your problem.