# How to make facebook login button required to click?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

```
<script>
    function initFbLogin() {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : '<?php echo $this->config_model->load_single('fbconnect_app_id'); ?>',
                status     : true, // check login status
                cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    setField();
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    FB.login();
                } else {
                    FB.login();
                }
            });
        };

        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        } (document));
    }

    function setField() {
        FB.api('/me', function(data) {
            //console.log('Good to see you, ' + data.name + '.' + data.id+' '+data.first_name+' '+data.last_name+' '+data.gender+' '+data.email+' '+data.username);
            // try to validate account that linked with facebook.
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url+'account/login/ajax_fb_login',
                type: 'POST',
                data: csrf_name+'='+csrf_value+'&account_email='+data.email+'&facebook_id='+data.id,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(logindata) {
                    if (logindata.login_result === true) {
                        <?php if (isset($go_to)) { ?> 
                        window.location = '<?php echo urldecode($go_to); ?>';
                        <?php } else { ?> 
                        window.location = base_url;
                        <?php } ?> 
                    } else {
                        alert(logindata.login_result_text);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
<fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1" scope="email,user_birthday"></fb:login-button>
```

This code make button login without click if user logged in to facebook.
How to make it required to click before login?

Comment: You mean that the user can enter to your app only after clicking on the login button. You dont want to take the facebook session and login automatically. Is that what you want?

Comment: @SahilMittal Yes that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `FB.Event.subscribe()` if you don't want to auto-login the user.

Instead, just create a normal button `<button></button>` and on its click perform actions you want using [`FB.getLoginstatus()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) and [`FB.login()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login). So, on click of this button do this:

```
$( "#my_fb_button" ).click(function() {
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
         setField();
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
        login();
      } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        login();
      }
   });
});

function login()
{
    FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
          setField();
        } else {
          console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,user_birthday'});
}
```

Hope the flow is clear now. Many apps use this flow too and it works like charm. Good luck!

Comment: If use custom, normal button i cannot get user email and birthday.

Comment: This works but apparently using a "normal" button leads to the Chrome popup blocker issues when the user is not authenticated with Facebook. I guess the facebook login button has something to prevent the pop-up blocker which the normal simple button doesn't.

Comment: The popup blocker is the browser's feature. The user have to manually disable the popup blocker for facebook to see the dialog OR you can use the url redirection instead of login button.

Answer (score 0):

I am at a similar question here and I found this post: [facebook API how is onlogin called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771534/facebook-api-how-is-onlogin-called)

There is an method to assign your javascript function to assign on the login button `onlogin='your_javascript_function()` to be added into your button.